# Simulate wireless network OMNet++

Tags: omnet++, inet

I'm trying to simulate a wireless network with 3 access point. I need to set the range of each AP and simulate mobile devices walking around these APs that are sending wireless sign.
I read that a good omnet framework to do so is the INET. I already ran some examples and tutorials but I still cant't do my experiment. Does anybody knows a step by step tutorial to simulate an AP sending sign for a mobility device?

Answer (score 1):

Googled for resources for INET and following these,

1. http://rockthevoid.tumblr.com/post/17374133262/omnet-and-how-to-create-tcp-applications
2. https://omnetpp.org/doc/inet/api-current/tutorials/wireless/